# php display categories and subcategories

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, do-while

Ok now i have two table `categories` and `subcategories` like this

```
Categories:
  id
  title
  description

Sub Categories:
  id
  catid
  title
  description
```

Now the '`catid`' of the subcategories will have the value of categories '`id`' and i want to group my and loop my categories and sub categories and display it like

```
Category
  subcat
  subcat

categories
  subcat
  subcat
```

Comment: Good, that looks nice. Now what is your question exactly :-) ? You need to be more specific. Show us what you have so far and what's not working/what you need hints on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$catquery = "select * from categories"; 
$res = mysql_query($catquery)

while (list($id, $title, $description) = mysql_fetch_row($res)){
     $subquery = "select id, title, description from subcategories where catid = {$id}";
     $res = mysql_query($subquery);
     echo("Category: {title} ({description})<br />");
     while (list($sid, $stitle, $sdescription) = mysql_fetch_row($res)){
          echo (" Subcategory: {stitle} {sdescription}<br />");
     }
}
```

This should display your categories and subcategories as such:

> Category: Category1 (This is
>   category1) 
>  Subcategory: SubCategory1
>   This is subcategory1 
>   Subcategory:
>   SubCategory2 This is subcategory2 
>   Category: Category2 (This is
>   category2)  
>  Subcategory: Subcategory3
>   This is subcategory3

and so on